# Python, LPTHW exercise 24, def function

Tags: python

I have started learning Python using LPTHW. I am not a computer scientist so I am still learningn the terms used. I have problems with the Exercise 24. 
I dont fully understand when we say beans, jars, crates = secret_formula, how does the program know the order of these variables in context to the defined function. I have tried to change the order of returned objects and this only changes the order of the varibales in the example bellow. I also went beans, crates, jars = secret_formula.. and the order its printed out didnt change. I quess I dont understand how is it assigned to the function.

```
print "Lets practice everything."

print 'You\'d need to know \'bout escapes with \\ that do \n newlines and \t tabs.'

poem = """
\tThe lovely World
with logic so firmly planted
cannnot discern \n the needs of love
nor comprehend passion from intuition
and requires an explanation
\n\t\twhere there is none.
"""

print "---------------"
print poem
print "---------------"

five = 10-2+3-6
print "This should be five: %s" % five

def secret_formula(started):
    jelly_beans = started *500
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000
    crates = jars / 100
    return jelly_beans, jars, crates

start_point = 10000
beans, jars,crates = secret_formula(start_point)

print "With a start_point of: %d" % start_point
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % (beans,jars, crates )

start_point = start_point /10

print "We can also do that this way:"
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars and %d crates" % secret_formula(start_point)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. `secret_formula` is returning them in that order.

Comment: You changed what where?

Comment: Turns out I am blind. When I changed the order of the retuned values the numbers changed. I thought it only changed the order for the second example but now I see it changed it the order for both.

Comment: Sorry guys, I am not very clear. I think I get it now.